# Screen transition in navigation is not possible in React Native Windows

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-native-windows

I'm doing screen transitions in react native windows.

The simple button transition

Home-> Movie-> Home

doesn't work.

There is no problem transitioning from Home to Movie, but when transitioning from Movie to Home,
The screen goes blank.

I haven't received any error messages, but can you tell what is the cause?

environment:

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-windows": "0.68.6"
```

source:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {ThemeProvider} from '@rneui/themed';

import theme from './src/styles/theme';

import Home from './src/page/Home/Home';
import Movie from './src/page/Movie/Movie';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Movie" component={Movie} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {Button} from '@rneui/themed';

const Home = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  console.log(navigation.getState());
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.centerText}>HOME</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Movie."
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Movie')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default Home;
```

Movie.js

```
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {Button} from '@rneui/themed';

const Movie = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  console.log(navigation.getState());
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.centerText}>MOVIE</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Home. "
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default Movie;
```

It is a video of the operation status.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-vQ4bMW_Yo7C1s8h5guohxr8FkDP1bZi/view?usp=sharing